# Export certificate as .p12 on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, private-key

I am trying to export an apple distribution code signing certificate into a .p12 format on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I have the certificate in my keychain and am unable to find the private key. All of the documentation I have read are from newer versions of OS X. Does anyone know how to find the private key on Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to export it with the Keychain Access utility. Select "My Certificates" from the Category section of its sidebar, and it'll show your certificates with their private keys associated. If you select the certificate in this mode and choose File menu > Export Items, it'll have the option to export it as a .p12 file.

If it doesn't appear in this mode, I'm pretty sure that means the keychain doesn't contain the corresponding private key.